# How can I customize /login/authenticate on Spring Security Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I' m performing a change to
`<g:form controller="login" action="authenticate" class="form">`, which redirects to authenticate contained on the plugin `/login/authenticate`.

How can I customize the path to another action which can perform session checking when the action will be called?

Answer (score 0):

You could do your own / custom authentication action as below.

```
    <!--Your login page gsp-->
    <g:form controller="login" action="auth" class="form">
```

Your GSP custom action

```
//inject springSecurityService this service in the login controller as def springSecurityService

        def auth(){
            def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
            if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
                redirect uri: config.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
                return
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own action and redirect to the default /login/authenticate apf url. You can do your checking in your action.

If you need to check something after the user is authenticated, you can simply override the action def ajaxSuccess() creating the controller with same name ie. LoginController.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security is built around filter chains. The correct way would be to create a new filter. You probably need to download the spring grails security core plugin and look at classes like GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to get a feel for how to do it.